# How to relog performance monitor circular log

Tags: performance, monitor, perfmon

I'm trying to relog performance monitor circular log.
When I do this with **"normal" binary** file, it's working correctly:

```
C:\PerfLogs\Admin\Test>relog DataCollector01.blg -f csv -o test.csv

Input
----------------
File(s):
     DataCollector01.blg (Binary)

Begin:    2016-11-22 8:18:18
End:      2016-11-22 8:21:18
Samples:  13

100.00%

Output
----------------
File:     test.csv

Begin:    2016-11-22 8:18:18
End:      2016-11-22 8:21:18
Samples:  13

The command completed successfully.
```

But when I created a **circular** log, then I get the error:

```
C:\PerfLogs\Admin\Test>relog DataCollector01.blg -f csv -o test.csv

Input
----------------
File(s):
     DataCollector01.blg (Binary)


Error:
Unable to read counter information and data from input binary log files.
```

The DataCollector is running. When I stop it, then I can relog the blg file.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot read a lot while it's open. You have to stop the logging first.